# Python pandas filling of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem with the filling of a Dataframe.
This is the initial situation (picture1)

[image]

My code runs like this (picture 2):
[image]

But I want this (picture3):
[image]

So if there a row from -1 to 4 empty, it should be empty. But if there are numbers it should be filled with "0"

My code looks like this...

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/Hanna/Code/ZERO.csv')


indx = df[df['D'] == -1].index.values

for i, j in zip(indx[:-1], indx[1:]):
df.loc[i:j-1, 'E'] = df.loc[i:j-1, 'E'].fillna(0)

    if j == indx[-1]:
    df.loc[j:, 'E'] = df.loc[j:, 'E'].fillna(0)
```

That my code, but I am not sure with the 'NaN'

d = {'A': [4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074], 'B': [SP000796746, SP000796746, SP000796746, SP000796746, SP000796746, SP000796746, SP000796746, SP000796746, SP000796746, SP000796746, SP000796746, SP000796746, SP000796746, SP000796746, SP000796746, SP000796746, SP000796746, SP000796746], 'C': [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'D': [0, 1000, 1000, 0, 0, 0, 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 0, 0, 0, 3000, 3000, 0], 'E': [2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000]}

Thank you Hanna

Maybe it does not work, because I do this before, with another column F:

```
indx = df[df['Diff Load Due Week'] == -1].index.values


for i, j in zip(indx[:-1], indx[1:]):
    df.loc[i:j-1, 'F'] = df.loc[i:j-1, 'F'].max()

if j == indx[-1]:
        df.loc[j:, 'F'] = df.loc[j:, 'F'].max()
```

Can it be, that I have to remove the index first?

That is my last output:

```
base_list =[-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]
df_c = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
[4000074],
["SP000796746","SP001811642"],
[201824, 201828, 201832, 201835, 201837, 201839, 201845, 201850, 201910, 201918, 201922, 201926, 201909, 201916, 201918, 201920],
base_list],

    names=["A", "B", "C", "D"]).to_frame(index=False)

# Verbinden der neuen Liste und der kleinen Rohdatenliste

df_3 = pd.merge(df_c, df_1, how='outer')

# Zusammengefügte Daten in Excel und csv speichern für Überprüfung und Weiterarbeit

df_3.to_csv('GROß.csv')
df_3.to_excel('GROß.xlsx')
```

## Einlesen der neu erstellten csv

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/Hanna/Desktop/Daten Projektseminar/Coding/GROß.csv')

#Index setzen für -1, damit Spalten und Reihen aufgefüllt werden können

indx = df[df['D'] == -1].index.values

#Aufüllen der Billings mit maximalen Wert

for i, j in zip(indx[:-1], indx[1:]):
    df.loc[i:j-1, 'F'] = df.loc[i:j-1, 'F'].max()

if j == indx[-1]:
        df.loc[j:, 'F'] = df.loc[j:, 'F'].max()
```

Comment: Please include your data as text, not pictures.

Comment: Hello, how can I do it out of excel?

Comment: Please include a reproducible sample of your data

Comment: You have your data in a pandas dataframe, simply do `print(df)` and copy and paste that in the question.

Comment: I added a list, hopefully it works with this

Comment: Because I can't see all rows if I print it in python

Comment: Few things you should consider when you are asking a question. 1) Avoid using screenshot  2) provide a sample data set so that others can try.  3) Ask your specific question very clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this should do the trick now:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#your data
d = {'A': [4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074,
   4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074, 4000074],
 'B': ['SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746',
   'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 
   'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746', 'SP000796746'],
 'C': [201926, 201926, 201926, 201926, 201926, 201926, 201909,201909, 201909, 201909, 201909, 
   201909, 201933, 201933, 201933, 201933, 201933, 201933],
 'D': [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
 'E': [np.nan, 1000, 1000, 0, 0, 0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3000, 3000, np.nan]}

#create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

#group sum column E by ID columns
groupedSum = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['E'].sum().reset_index()

#loop over unique IDs
for i, row in groupedSum.iterrows():
    #define values
    idValue = groupedSum.at[i,'C']
    sumValue = groupedSum.at[i,'E']
    #if sum is not zero
    if (sumValue != 0):
        #change values to zero if greater than zero
        df['E'].loc[df['C'] == idValue] = df['E'].apply(lambda x: x if x > 0 else 0)

print(df)

          A            B       C  D       E
0   4000074  SP000796746  201926 -1     0.0
1   4000074  SP000796746  201926  0  1000.0
2   4000074  SP000796746  201926  1  1000.0
3   4000074  SP000796746  201926  2     0.0
4   4000074  SP000796746  201926  3     0.0
5   4000074  SP000796746  201926  4     0.0
6   4000074  SP000796746  201909 -1     NaN
7   4000074  SP000796746  201909  0     NaN
8   4000074  SP000796746  201909  1     NaN
9   4000074  SP000796746  201909  2     NaN
10  4000074  SP000796746  201909  3     NaN
11  4000074  SP000796746  201909  4     NaN
12  4000074  SP000796746  201933 -1     0.0
13  4000074  SP000796746  201933  0     0.0
14  4000074  SP000796746  201933  1     0.0
15  4000074  SP000796746  201933  2  3000.0
16  4000074  SP000796746  201933  3  3000.0
17  4000074  SP000796746  201933  4     0.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed explanation, unfortunately I am not a native speaker so it is not so easy for me to explain correctly. 

Unfortunately your solution does not help me yet. Unfortunately I have to upload a picture for better understanding. 

If there is a value in column 'E' like for example ""1000"", then from -1 to 4 the section around this number should be filled up with 0. As you can see on the third picture. 
If there is no value from -1 to 4, then nothing should be filled in there, so also no "0". This is also shown in picture 3

Comment: above i uploaded a picture for better understanding (picture 1)

Comment: Ok got it now, i have just updated the answer to do what you want!

Comment: Yes that works nearly like want. Thank you very much. The only thing, that does not work ist this ['A', 'B', 'C'] But I try to solve it

Comment: i had a typo in there when i first pasted the answer but did edit it again, so you might have copied it with that still in, try it again with the updated code above, if still doesn't work, let me know what error message you're getting. Finally, if it's working for you, kindly accept the answer for others passing by!

Comment: Now its working, but E ist filled with "0" everywhere and not with NaN. Do you know why i could happen? Yes, I will accept it

Comment: Umm, can your run a dtypes on your original dataframe? And then on the grouped dataframe?

Comment: the dytypes are the same-.-

Comment: not interested in them being the same or not, what are the dtypes? reason i'm asking is the conditions within the loop are desined with the assumption that 'D' and 'E' are numeric, but are they in your DF? In anyway, can add at the ned of your post the code you're using and the output?

Comment: D= int and F= float

Comment: Please add your most recent code and the output at the end of your question.

Comment: I added a peace of code, which I do before your code for another column 'F'. And there I set a index, maybe this is the problem... Can I remove the index, before python starts with your code? It takes me hours and always something is wrong..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213954/discussion-between-mit-and-hanna).