# How to selectively transpose and stack columns in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have some example data that is coming in an undesirable format as seen below:

`+-------+-----------------+---------------+------------------+------+
| Month | Alcohol 5 hours | Sugar 5 hours | Alcohol 10 hours | Tank |
+-------+-----------------+---------------+------------------+------+
| May   | 2               | 30            | 4                | X    |
+-------+-----------------+---------------+------------------+------+
| June  | 5               | 20            | 10               | Y    |
+-------+-----------------+---------------+------------------+------+`

*there are more columns for sugars 10 & 50 hours and alcohol 50 hours. Too long to put here neatly

I would like to selectively transpose and stack the data like this:

`+-------+------------+-----------------+---------------+------+--+--+--+
| Month | Time (hrs) | Alcohol         | Sugar         | Tank |  |  |  |
+-------+------------+-----------------+---------------+------+--+--+--+
| May   | 5          | 2               | 30            | X    |  |  |  |
+-------+------------+-----------------+---------------+------+--+--+--+
| May   | 10         | 4               | 15            | X    |  |  |  |
+-------+------------+-----------------+---------------+------+--+--+--+
| May   | 50         | 10              | 4             | X    |  |  |  |
+-------+------------+-----------------+---------------+------+--+--+--+
| June  | 5          | 5               | 20            | Y    |  |  |  |
+-------+------------+-----------------+---------------+------+--+--+--+
| June  | 10         | 10              | 12            | Y    |  |  |  |
+-------+------------+-----------------+---------------+------+--+--+--+
| June  | 50         | 15              | 2             | Y    |  |  |  |
+-------+------------+-----------------+---------------+------+--+--+--+`

Any help would be greatly appreciated to point me in the right direction! I could probably hard code and selectively slice each column to transpose and combine later...but maybe there is more refined way. It would be great to make this more flexible for receiving many more columns with time points as headers.

I have been reading the file in as a dataframe

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df = df.rename(columns = lambda x: x.replace(' hours',''))

df = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),
                     stubnames=['Alcohol','Sugar'],
                     i='index',
                     j='Time (hrs)',
                      sep=' '
                     ).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
   Time (hrs) Product Month  Alcohol  Sugar
0           5       X   May        2     30
1           5       Y  June        5     20
2          10       X   May        4     15
3          10       Y  June       10     12
4          50       X   May       10      4
5          50       Y  June       15      2
```

Or `split` by all categories columns with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Month','Product'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.replace(' hours', '').str.split(expand=True, n=1)
df1 = df1.rename_axis([None, 'Time (hrs)'], axis=1).stack().reset_index()
print (df1)
  Month Product Time (hrs)  Alcohol  Sugar
0   May       X         10        4     15
1   May       X          5        2     30
2   May       X         50       10      4
3  June       Y         10       10     12
4  June       Y          5        5     20
5  June       Y         50       15      2
```

Comment: Always there's something to learn from your answers +1. @jezrael Can you answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61799492/12833166)?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - thank you, hmm, not sure if non loops solution is possible there :(

Comment: yeah i guess, I was thinking of grouping the dataframe by the sequence `-1,0..4` and then applying `transform`. Could it be possible anyway?